# Google SceneForm transparency problems

Tags: android, sceneform

I'm trying to show a 3d model with alpha values in the baseColor of it's texture just to get used with arCore SDK for Android. The problem is that in Android studio the model looks good but once in runtime on my phone the alpaha channel is not being used. 
I try all the blending option on my custom material, setting the maskThreshold option manually and changing the alpha channel in my texture.

**custom_material.mat**

```
{
  animations: [
    {
      path: 'sampledata/007/model007.fbx',
    },
  ],
  materials: [
    {
      name: 'diffuse',
      parameters: [
        {
          alphaFactor: 1.0,
        },
        {
          baseColorMap: '007f',
        },
        {
          reflectanceMap: '007s',
        },
        {
          roughnessMap: 0.6,
        },
      ],
      source: 'sampledata/pbr.mat',
    },
  ],
  model: {
    attributes: [
      'Position',
      'TexCoord',
      'Orientation',
      'BoneIndices',
      'BoneWeights',
    ],
    collision: {},
    file: 'sampledata/007/model007.fbx',
    name: 'model007',
    recenter: 'root',
  },
  samplers: [
    {
      file: 'sampledata/007\\007f.png',
      name: '007f',
      pipeline_name: '007f.png',
    },
    {
      file: 'sampledata/007\\007s.jpg',
      name: '007s',
      pipeline_name: '007s.jpg',
    }
  ],
  version: '0.54:2',
}
```

**MainActivity.java** (just the sceneform part)

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, R.raw.model007)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(
                        modelRenderable -> {
                            faceRegionsRenderable = modelRenderable;
                            modelRenderable.setShadowCaster(false);
                            modelRenderable.setShadowReceiver(false);
                        });

        ArSceneView sceneView = arFragment.getArSceneView();
        sceneView.setCameraStreamRenderPriority(Renderable.RENDER_PRIORITY_FIRST);
        Scene scene = sceneView.getScene();
        scene.addOnUpdateListener(
                (FrameTime frameTime) -> {
                    if (faceRegionsRenderable == null) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Collection<AugmentedFace> faceList =
                            sceneView.getSession().getAllTrackables(AugmentedFace.class);

                    // Make new AugmentedFaceNodes for any new faces.
                    for (AugmentedFace face : faceList) {
                        if (!faceNodeMap.containsKey(face)) {
                            AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = new AugmentedFaceNode(face);
                            faceNode.setParent(scene);
                            faceNode.setFaceRegionsRenderable(faceRegionsRenderable);
                            faceNodeMap.put(face, faceNode);
                        }
                    }
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode>> iter =
                            faceNodeMap.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (iter.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<AugmentedFace, AugmentedFaceNode> entry = iter.next();
                        AugmentedFace face = entry.getKey();
                        if (face.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.STOPPED) {
                            AugmentedFaceNode faceNode = entry.getValue();
                            faceNode.setParent(null);
                            iter.remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**directory struct**

```
sampledata
-custom_material.mat
-007
--007f.png
--007s.jpg
--007r.jpg
--model007.fbx
--model007.sfa
res
-raw
--model007.sfb
```

[capture in runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0iJJ.jpg)

[screenshoot of sceneform viewer in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPdbs.jpg)

Any idea of whats happening?
thanks in advance!